# handler crash when using on asytask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I'm using handler in asyntask which make my application crash. I have uploaded my project here https://www.zeta-uploader.com/998997295

It is working and only the problem is using handler inside asytask makes application crash.
My question is how do i get value of for loop at in json parsing show on postexecute?

Is there any alternative idea firstly get values then show on postexecute?

If i declare this line on main code  application crash plz fix my problem

```
row4 = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.row2, null);




           public class fifthscreen extends Activity {
String num = null;

long Menu_ID;
String dish_name;
View row4;
int IOConnect = 0;
View row3;

String status;
private static Handler handler;
HorizontalListView listview;
CategoryListAdapter3 cla;
String DescriptionAPI;

TextView txt1, txt2, txt3;
ImageView img1;
String URL, URL2;
String SelectMenuAPI;
static ArrayList<Long> Category_ID = new ArrayList<Long>();
static ArrayList<String> Category_name = new ArrayList<String>();
static ArrayList<String> Category_image = new ArrayList<String>();
public static String allergen2;
private AQuery androidAQuery;
String name;

String description;
String url1;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fifthscreen);
    handler = new Handler();
    img1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.test_button_image);

    txt1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.menuname);
    txt3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.description);

    androidAQuery = new AQuery(this);




    new getDataTask().execute();

}

void clearData() {
    Category_ID.clear();
    Category_name.clear();
    Category_image.clear();

}

public class getDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    getDataTask() {

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        parseJSONData();
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (IOConnect == 0) {
            txt1.setText(name);
            txt3.setText(description);
            androidAQuery.id(img1).image(url1, false, false);


        }
    }
}

public void parseJSONData() {

    SelectMenuAPI = "http://198.57.208.46/~school/api/index/getDishDiscription?dish_name=American%20Cheese%20Burger";

    clearData();
    URL = SelectMenuAPI;
    URL2 = URL.replace(" ", "%20");

    try {

        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpConnectionParams
                .setConnectionTimeout(client.getParams(), 15000);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(client.getParams(), 15000);
        HttpUriRequest request = new HttpGet(URL2);
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
        InputStream atomInputStream = response.getEntity().getContent();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                atomInputStream), 8192);

        String line;
        String str = "";
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            str += line;
        }

        JSONObject json2 = new JSONObject(str);

        status = json2.getString("status");
        if (status.equals("1")) {

            JSONArray school2 = json2.getJSONArray("data");

            for (int i = 0; i < school2.length(); i++) {

                name = school2.getJSONObject(0).getString("name");

                description = school2.getJSONObject(0).getString(
                        "description");

                url1 = school2.getJSONObject(0).getString("image");

            }

            JSONObject school3 = json2.getJSONObject("dish_nutrition");

            final TableLayout table = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.table2);

            for (int j = 0; j < school3.length(); j++) {

                String s = String.valueOf(j + 1);

                row3 = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.rows, null);
                ((TextView) row3.findViewById(R.id.localTime))
                        .setText(school3.getJSONObject(s).getString("qty"));
                ((TextView) row3.findViewById(R.id.apprentTemp))
                        .setText(school3.getJSONObject(s).getString("name"));

                fifthscreen.getHandler().post(new Runnable() {

                    public void run() {
                        table.addView(row3);
                    }
                });

            }



            final LinearLayout table3 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.table3);

            JSONArray school5 = json2.getJSONArray("dish_ingredient");

            for (int i = 0; i < school5.length(); i++) {

                row4 = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.row2, null);
                ((TextView) row4.findViewById(R.id.name)).setText(school5
                        .getJSONObject(i).getString("name"));
                ((TextView) row4.findViewById(R.id.subingredients))
                        .setText(school5.getJSONObject(i).getString(
                                "sub_ingredients"));

                fifthscreen.getHandler().post(new Runnable() {

                    public void run() {
                        table3.addView(row4);
                    }
                });

            }

        }

        else {

            JSONArray school2 = json2.getJSONArray("data");
            for (int i = 0; i < school2.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject object = school2.getJSONObject(i);

                Category_ID.add((long) i);
                Category_name.add(object.getString("name"));

            }

        }

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        IOConnect = 1;
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private static Handler getHandler() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return handler;
}
```

}

Comment: Move the code from `parseJSONData()` to `doInBackground()` and put the code that updates the `UI` inside `onProgressUpdate()`. Then you can call `publishProgress()` inside of your `for loop`.

Comment: i think i answered a similar question of your yesterday

Comment: how? give me nay example. is only single activity code i atect my project file it contain single acitivity only plz fix my problem im so much in trouble

Comment: i try so many adice noting work plz i attech my source file also https://www.zeta-uploader.com/998997295 this url  pl fix my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Handler is created on the ui thread

When you create a new Handler, it is bound to the thread / message queue of the thread that is creating it -- from that point on, it will deliver messages and runnables to that message queue and execute them as they come out of the message queue.

Also you infalte a layout and initialize and update your views in doInbackground which is wrong.

You call `parseJSONData()` in `doInbackground`. In  `parseJSONData()` you have the below. You cannot update ui from a background thread

```
row3 = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.rows, null);
((TextView) row3.findViewById(R.id.localTime))
.setText(school3.getJSONObject(s).getString("qty"));
 ((TextView) row3.findViewById(R.id.apprentTemp))
 .setText(school3.getJSONObject(s).getString("name"));
```

Return the JSONObject in your `doInbackground` an update your textview's in `onPostExecute`

Edit:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    String _response;
//  ArrayList<String> nam = new ArrayList<String>();
//  ArrayList<String> desc = new ArrayList<String>();
//  ArrayList<String> ur = new ArrayList<String>();
    TextView tv;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        tv= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        new TheTask().execute();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }


public class TheTask extends AsyncTask<Void, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... arg0) {



            try {
                String query = URLEncoder.encode("American%20Cheese%20Burger", "utf-8");
                String url = "http://198.57.208.46/~school/api/index/getDishDiscription?dish_name=American%20Cheese%20Burger";
                Log.i("url",""+url);
                HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url); 
                HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
                HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();
                 _response=EntityUtils.toString(resEntity);
//               JSONObject json = new JSONObject(_response);
//               String status = json.getString("status");
//               if (status.equals("1")) {
//              JSONArray school2 = json.getJSONArray("data");
//                for (int i = 0; i < school2.length(); i++) {
//                       String name = school2.getJSONObject(0).getString("name");
//                       nam.add(name);
//                       String  description = school2.getJSONObject(0).getString(
//                                           "description");
//                      desc.add(description);
//                      String url1 = school2.getJSONObject(0).getString("image");
//                      ur.add(url1);
//                   
//              }
//               }
//                JSONObject school3 = json.getJSONObject("dish_nutrition"); 
//                JSONObject jb2 = school3.getJSONObject("1");
//                String name1 =jb2.getString("name");
//                String qty =jb2.getString("qty");
//                JSONObject jb3 = school3.getJSONObject("2");
//                String name2 =jb3.getString("name");
//                String qty2 =jb3.getString("qty");
//               JSONArray jr = json.getJSONArray("dish_ingredient");
//                 for(int i=0;i<jr.length();i++)
//                 {
//                   JSONObject jb = (JSONObject) jr.get(i);
//                   String n = jb.getString("name");
//                   String sub= jb.getString("sub_ingredients");
//                 }
            }catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        return _response;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
   tv.setText(result);

    }
}
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
        android:text="TextView" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

snap

[image]

Apart from the above you parsing also is wrong.

```
dish_nutrition": { 
            "1": {
                "name": "Cholesterol ",
                "qty": "2"
            },
            "2": {
                "name": "Chol (mg)",
                "qty": "3"
             }
```

You have

```
  JSONObject school3 = json2.getJSONObject("dish_nutrition");
```

And then

```
  for (int j = 0; j < school3.length(); j++) {  // school3 is not a json array
```

`{` represents json object node

`[` represents json array node

Its upto you to parse and display the values in your views. Modify the above according to your requirement

Comment: i attech my project file plz tell me what i do? i just want to show forloop values in two textview until forlop not finish how do i move that  part on postexecute

Comment: i know bt what i do? how i show textview values on postexecute?? someone give me advce use handler but is crash sometime

Comment: @user2844177 never ask others to run your code. You need to take the suggestion posted and make changes accordingly nobody is going to do your work

Comment: Raghunandan u mean get only http response on postexecute then using forloop thir??

Comment: after getting result at this line tv.setText(result);??what i do?? write again this all code
JSONObject json2 = new JSONObject(str);

   status = json2.getString("status");
   if (status.equals("1")) {

    JSONArray school2 = json2.getJSONArray("data");

.....

Comment: @user2844177 you can do your parsing in `doInbackground` store the parsed value in a list or a hashmap and then use the same to disply it in your views. I don't know what you are looking for. But this is more than i can help. It does not matter where you parse your data but remember to update ui only in onPostExecute.

Comment: i guess is work i do what u say and past al code which u comment and is work now only tell why u change my http code?  what is mean by this line  String query ???

Comment: Raghunandan ur code is work now only twllme whay u change my http code? why remove input stream buffer what is mean by this line String query = URLEncoder.encode("American%20Cheese%20Burger", "utf-8");??

Comment: @user2844177 why you not understand. its url encoding. i din't change anything i made it shorter. i am no here to explain you line by line what is happening. Pls read the docs and understand the basics. also if it works you need to mark the answer as accepted by clicking the tick once. The only thing i changed was this `HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();
                 _response=EntityUtils.toString(resEntity)` which gives the string response.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot update the UI from a background thread so where you use

```
row4 = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.row2, null);
```

this needs to be done in the `onPostExecute` along with any other UI elements that you want to update

**Edit**

make `parseJSONData()` return your json string to the onPostExecute

```
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    return parseJSONData();
}
```

then do everything else in your onPostExecute

**Edit 2**

your asynctask needs to look like this

```
public class getDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

getDataTask() {

}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    return parseJSONData();
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    //result is the json string you go back from the server parse it in here now
}
```

}

Comment: i did but if i did n postexecute then forloop only show last value

Comment: run my source code i attech project file in this url and see https://www.zeta-uploader.com/998997295

Comment: return the list of schools and loop through them in the `onPostExecute`

Comment: i wirte this line row4 = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.row2, null); on postexecute application crash now

Comment: look at the stacktrace and see what the error is, learn how to do some problem solving. Moving just that line will do nothing you need to move everything there that you need to update the UI with. we are not going to do it for you

Comment: application not work n android 4.o or above is crash

Comment: you are not listening to me!! I did not say move everything to the onPostExecute did I, no I said move all UI updating to the onPOstExecute. look at the stack trace and see the error, you will learn a lot from looking at the error. you will also see that it says you cannot run network operations on the UI thread so they have to be done in the doInBackground

Comment: not work its say change return type of parseJSONData(); to void

Comment: u mean move this lines on postexecute   ((TextView) row3.findViewById(R.id.localTime))
       .setText(school3.getJSONObject(s).getString("qty"));
     ((TextView) row3.findViewById(R.id.apprentTemp))
       .setText(school3.getJSONObject(s).getString("name"));?? then how i store json values??

Comment: clearly you need to change the variable in the onPostExecute to accept a string. see my edit

Comment: your network operation is in there then return the json string

Comment: what linesi wirte on postexecute?? all this  ((TextView) row3.findViewById(R.id.localTime))
       .setText(school3.getJSONObject(s).getString("qty"));
     ((TextView) row3.findViewById(R.id.apprentTemp))
       .setText(school3.getJSONObject(s).getString("name"));

       table.addView(row3);
      }
     });  or just table.addView(row3);

Comment: This is not the 5th time I have told you what to do, if it is anything related to the UI it needs to go into the onPostExecute. If you cannot figure it out after all this then you need to do more research on how AsyncTasks work

Comment: i did i writ this line on postexecute table.addView(row3);
    table3.addView(row4);   code is working but its show only lastvalue of forloop in textview

Comment: plz just 1 time run my code file which i attech above and see ur self

Comment: no my code is fine. if u run my code which i attech without any changing is work fine but when changing what u say nothing happen see ur self